# ng2-daterangePicker: unable to clear input when reseting the form(Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, angular-forms

I am using ng2-daterangepicker in my Angular Project and I need to clear the input field while I reset my Angular Form.
I have used "autoUpdateInput:false" in my ngOnit() function and I set it to true when I apply the dates. So, the field is clear when I first load the page but I need to bind it to the reset form function as well.

My html tag for daterangePicker:
`<input class="input-group input-group-xs form-control input-sm" type="text" name="daterangeInput"daterangepicker [options]="dateRangeOptions" (selected)="selectedDate($event)" />`

My reset Function: (daterange is a variable of the DateRangePickerComponent)

```
     private resetSearch(event) : void {
        this.breaksForm = this.fb.group({
              ...
        })
       this.daterange.settings={autoUpdateInput:true};
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was known by developer and was corrected in 1.6.0 version.

There is a button clear in datepicker, or if you can link your datepicker to NgModel and reset your model on NgInit method